# Sync Specflow scenarios (feature file scenarios) with Azure DevOps Test plan using specsync

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, bdd, specflow

Specflow scenarios can be sync with MTM. But is it possible to Sync Specflow scenarios with Azure DevOps Test plan using specsync? If yes, please mention steps. I need to upload scenarios to Azure DevOps test plan (as Test cases) from Visual Studio.

Comment: MTM is just a front end for working with test work items. The web-driven test explorer is different front end for working with the same underlying data. There's no reason it wouldn't work. But the best way to answer your question is to **contact the maintainer of the tool in question and ask them**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`But is it possible to Sync Specflow scenarios with Azure DevOps Test plan using specsync?`

Yes, it's able to do this.  [From official link](https://www.specsolutions.eu/services/specsync/):

> **Is it possible to synchronize SpecFlow scenarios to existing Azure DevOps Test Cases?**
>
> Yes. If you synchronize a test case which does not have a test case
>   tag yet, SpecSync will create a new one and tags the scenario. But if
>   you add the test case tag manually (in the format of @tc:123),
>   referring to an existing test case in Azure DevOps, SpecSync will
>   update that test case at the next synchronization.

More details about the detail tutorials please take a look at [here](https://specsolutions.gitbook.io/specsync/getting-started/getting-started-specflow).